# What's the difference between Autofac.WebApi and Autofac.WebApi2?

Tags: autofac

What's the difference between Autofac.WebApi and Autofac.WebApi2?

When I add the Autofac.WebApi2 NuGet Package I'm not able to add a "using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution was to remove the NuGet packages and add them again.